# MongoDb - checking existence of param in array during $addFields

Tags: mongodb, exists

given this fantasy dataset (sorry in advance but I couldn't manage to format it properly):

[image]

I would need to make a MongoDb pipe where a new field is created and, this new field, should be able to add a parameter valued with an empty string whene the "k" parameter is missing or empty.

Here is my attempt:

```
...    
{
    "$addFields": {
        "colors_field": {
            "r": "$colors.r",
            "g": "$colors.g",
            "b": "$colors.b",
            "k": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                       "$or": [
                            {"$eq": [ "$colors.k", "" ]},
                            {"$eq": [ "$colors.k", null ]},
                            {"$colors.k": { "$exists": false}}
                            ]
                    },
                    "then": "",
                    "else": "$colors.k"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with the $exists but I can't make it work because of the way I call the value to check: either I put "$colors.k" and it returns a "*MongoError: Unrecognized expression*" or I don't and it'll return a "*MongoError: FieldPath field names may not contain '.'*".
I also tried to check for the length of that field but it'll crash if said field is missing.

Comment: try to replace the `$cond` with `$ifnull`  like `{"k" : { $ifNull: [ "$colors.k", "" ] }}`   this means that if `color.k` doesn't exist or has null value, to take the value "", which is what you want i think.

Comment: Looks like working! I still can't wrap my head around how that should be working though, if I don't state the entity owning "k" how does it know where to look for it?
Anyway, if you post it as an answer I'll flag it as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you are using a query operatos `$exists`
inside a pipeline (only `$match` stage allows this).

We dont have an "$exists" operator in aggregation but we can do it using `$type` and "missing", but here you want exists or null, so `$ifnull` is the right way to do it(that does exaclty this,name is missleading, its if not-exists or null).

Query (3 ways to do it)

1. `$type` and "missing" (the right way to go if you wanted only exists), here you want null, also so it becomes bigger query
2. `$ifnull` this is the shortest way
3. `$cond`  not-exists or null are both false values, so this works also, BUT
   be careful with this, because if color was false, it would make it also ""

*in your case the short and safe solution is the 2

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-bKNz7v_m-1)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "k-cond": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$colors.k",
                  null
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$colors.k"
                  },
                  "missing"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "",
          "$colors.k"
        ]
      },
      "k-ifnull": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$colors.k",
          ""
        ]
      },
      "k-if": {
        "$cond": [
          "$colors.k",
          "$colors.k",
          ""
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```